# Cannot parse response error while consuming SOAP service with node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service using [node-soap module](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap). However, I get ***'Cannot parse response'*** error while calling one of the method of the web service.

Here is the implementation:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://myservice.com/MyService.svc?wsdl';
var args = {
    Username: '***',
    Password: '***'
};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if (!err) {      
        client.MyService(args, function(err, response) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('MyService response:', response);
            } else {
                console.log('Error in MyService:', err);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Error in createClient: ', err);
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. While the web service expecting **application/soap+xml** content type, the content type was **text/xml**. So I added **forceSoap12Headers: true** among *createClient()* parameters to force the node-soap to use SOAP 1.2 version. Also, I added the **ws-addressing** headers to soap header because of *The message with To ' ' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher* error.

The overall code:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://myservice.com/MyService.svc?wsdl';
var args = {
    Username: '***',
    Password: '***'
};
var soapOptions = {
    forceSoap12Headers: true
};
var soapHeaders = {
    'wsa:Action': 'http://tempuri.org/MyPortName/MyAction',
    'wsa:To': 'http://myservice.com/MyService.svc'
};

soap.createClient(url, soapOptions, function(err, client) {
    if (!err) {
        client.addSoapHeader(soapHeaders, '', 'wsa', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing');
        client.MyService(args, function(err, response) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('MyService response:', response);
            } else {
                console.log('Error in MyService:', err);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Error in createClient: ', err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code
client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('username', 'password'));
after your create client. It worked for me:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://myservice.com/MyService.svc?wsdl';
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
if (!err) {      
      client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('username', 'password'));
      client.MyService(args, function(err, response) {
      if (!err) {
            console.log('MyService response:', response);
        } else {
            console.log('Error in MyService:', err);
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log('Error in createClient: ', err);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated npm soap version and it worked for me